# Set Pre trained model variables to non trainable Inception 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am download [pre trained model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v1.py), Google Net Inception V1 to extract features from video frames. Then followed by few trainable variables. I have two doubts to be addressed.

1. tf.trainable_variables() includes variables list of pre trained model

[image: tf.trainable_variables() includes variables list of pre trained model]

2. saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file) returns NoneType for pre trained model

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow `Saver` accepts `Variable` list when constructing to tell which `Variable`s to restore or save, default it will find all the Variables in the default graph.

And the `optimizer` operators also accept `Variable` list to tell which Variables to optimize when training, and it also default find all the `Variable`s in the default graph;

You can define 2 `Saver`s, one for load the `InceptionV1` `Variable`s, one for your own `Variable`s.

And when constructing `optimizer` you can pass your own `Variable`s to parameter `var_list`, so the train will just update your own `Variable`s but not the `InceptionV1` `Variable`s.

Comment: the problem occurs when I initialized the variables I must not initialize InceptionV1 as I am restoring them but both tf.trainable_variables()  and tf.global_variables_initializer() I guess initialize all variables including InceptionV1.

Comment: I understand your answer Moreover, I have been adopting the same approach. But how do I initialized only "my own variable" because tf.global_variables_initializer() also reinitialized "Inception model variables".

Comment: You can call `Saver.restore` after `sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )`

Comment: var_list = [var for var in  tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='my_scope')]
var_list_init= tf.variables_initializer(var_list)
sess.run(var_list_init) work for me